# How to set multiple folders' templates at the same time on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I've tried selecting multiple folders at a time, going into properties, then customize and setting to optimize for say pictures. However if I do it this way it won't apply to all of them; it will only apply it if I select them individually. This is annoying as I have hundreds of folders I'd need to apply it for.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the view templates for each of the common FolderTypes:
[image]

To cover the assignable FolderTypes templates, you'll have to use `Apply to Folders` a total of six times, once for each FolderType.

1. Open a folder that uses the template you want to modify.
2. Set the view options to your liking (including columns for Details even if the final default is List, Tiles, or Icons)
3. **View** Ribbon -> **Options** -> **View** tab -> **Apply to Folders**

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

After your customized one folder you fill find a file `desktop.ini` in the root of that folder. Just copy that file to all other folders which should get the same customization.

Depending on the number of folder, you can use PowerShell to copy `desktop.ini`